# NavigationController wont push from function call + swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am basically trying to recreate whatsapp. My MainVC has a TableView that shows all current conversations and has a push segue to the ChatVC to display the entire conversation.

When a user wants to start a new conversation they click the button on the top right corner and the UserListVC comes from the bottom and displays a list of users.

My thinking here is that when a user clicks a user the "UsersListVC" dismisses (showing the mainVC) and calls a function to open up the ChatVC. However I havent been able call a function successfully after this dimiss from MainVC.

[image]

Please not right now I am not pushing any data through I just want to get the segues working correctly

**MainVC.swift**

```
func showChatVC() {

    print("FUnction called")
    let showChat = ChatVC()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(showChat, animated: false)

}
```

**UsersListVC.swift**

```
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            dismiss(animated: true) { 
                MainVC().showChatVC()
            }
        }
```

I have tried a few different variations and I cant seem to call the function in MainVC at all. Am I being too stubborn with my thinking doing the segues this way? Should I have a direct segue from UsersListVC to ChatVC

Comment: What is `dismiss(animated: ) { }`?

Comment: In this line let showChat = ChatVC(), you are creating a new instance of chat VC. instead, you need to access the "instance" you created in the storyboard. To do that, give the segue an identifier and call performSegueWithIdentifier method.

Comment: I tried putting my performSegue call into my function showChatVC but I cant even get that function showChatVC to be called when I select a row in my NewMessageVC

Comment: Or am I think of how to implement this wrong and I should just have a segue from my NewMessageVC to the chat after a user is selected?

Comment: Still the same problem, if you print out self.MessagesController?, i guess it will be nil. This is because the new instance of chat VC you created, does not have a reference to the MessageVC.

Comment: self.MessagesController does return nil ... :(

Comment: How are you trying to call showChatVC?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry once a user selects a table row the dismiss is called and throws a completion handler that tries to call the showChatVC() function

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I see that now.

Comment: Have you tried pushing the original MessagesVC in the segue from MessagesVC to New MessageVC? If you store it in your New MessageVC you might be able to reliably call it.

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you are asking. The segue from MessagesVC to NewMessageVC works fine and I have a function that dismisses it clear on the cancel button press that works fine as well. The segue from MessagesVC to chat vc also works as it should. NewMessagesVC should probably be named UsersVC as you select a user (table row) and then it brings you to ChatVC. The way this is set up I expect the behaviour to be: user clicks table row -> NewMessageVC dismisses (MessagesVC is now visible) -> Immediately after the app pushes from MessagesVC to ChatVC

Comment: can you attach your project

Comment: `MainVC().showChatVC()` creates a new instance of `MainVC`. This new instance is not in the view hierarchy and also not in a navigation controller. Therefore the call `navigationController?.pushViewController(showChat, animated: false)` does nothing, because `navigationController` is `nil`. You need to retrieve a reference to the existing `MainVC` instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @Jiri how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lots of answers here, thought I should add my go to solution for these types of problems, using a delegate pattern.

With a delegate you can call a function in MainVC from UsersListVC, this makes it much easier to segue to ChatVC and will also help when you are passing the selected user to ChatVC.

To make a delegate pattern you:

1. create a protocol which specifies the function your delegate class must implement, typically I do this above the delegate class, so MainVC.

   ```
   protocol UsersListDelegate: class {

       func newConversationCreated(withUser user: AnyObject)

   }
   ```

---

2. have your delegate class (MainVC) conform to the protocol and implement the required function

   ```
   class MainVC: UIViewController, UsersListDelegate {

       func newConversationCreated(withUser user: AnyObject) {

           //I'll fill this in later in my answer

       }

   }
   ```

---

3. create a variable in UsersListVC to hold the delegate class in

   ```
   class UsersListVC: UIViewController {

       weak var delegate: UsersListDelegate!

   }
   ```

---

4. when you present UsersList from MainVC set the delegate variable to  MainVC (self), for example if you segue to UsersList then this can be done in prepare for segue.

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       if let destination = segue.destination as? UsersListVC {

           destination.delegate = self

       }

   }
   ```

   or if you present it without a segue:

   ```
   func presentUsersList() {

       let userListsVC = UsersListVC()
       userListsVC.delegate = self
       self.present(userListsVC, animated: true)

   }
   ```

---

Your delegate pattern is finished now. To call the delegate function when you want to create the new conversation and dismiss UserListsVC, you do it like this

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        delegate.newConversationCreated(withUser: /*Your User Object*/)

    }
```

And in MainVC you can implement the newConversationCreated function to:

- Dismiss UserLists
- Create ChatVC
- Pass on the user to ChatVC
- Present ChatVC

e.g.

```
    func newConversationCreated(withUser user: AnyObject) {

        dismiss(animated: true) { 

            let showChat = ChatVC()
            showChat.user = user
            navigationController?.pushViewController(showChat, animated: false)

        }

    }
```

---

p.s. It may seem weird to call dismiss from MainVC, but this is actually best practice according to apple (see the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047430/should-i-call-dismissviewcontroller-on-the-modal-uiviewcontroller-or-the-uiviewc) for why). It will dismiss UserLists don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code

> Step - 1

- set up the storyboard identifiers .
- then try below code

  **MainVC.swift**

  ```
   func showChatVC() {

    let showChat = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChatVc_ID") as! ChatVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(showChat, animated: false)    

   }
  ```

**UsersListVC.swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true) { 
   let mainVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainVC_ID") as! MainVC 
   mainVC.showChatVC()
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send action from your `tableView's didSelectRow` method like

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("showChatVC", to: nil, from: nil, forEvent: nil)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `NotificationCenter`:

In `MainVC` register for `NewChatCreateNotification` like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(autoNavigateToNewChat(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NewChatCreateNotification"), object: nil)
```

Still in `MainVC`, in the `autoNavigateToNewChat:` method, push `ChatVC`

Then post your notification after you dismiss `UsersListVC`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Use this dict to populate the userInfo of the notification, then you can use it when you push to ChatVC. 
    //You can obviously add more info to it like userId etc. as long as the data conforms to: [AnyHashable: Any]
    let dict = ["chatId" as NSString : <the selected chatId> as NSNumber]

    dismiss(animated: true) { 
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NewChatCreatedNotification"), object: self, userInfo: dict as [AnyHashable: Any])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work with your storyboard setup. Make sure to set the segue identifiers in the storyboard. I am using a button instead of table view cell in the `UsersListVC`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

internal enum SegueIdentifier: String {
    case showChat = "showChat"
    case showUserList = "showUserList"
}

internal final class MainVC: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == SegueIdentifier.showUserList.rawValue, let vc = segue.destination as? UsersListVC {
            vc.completion = {
                [weak self] in self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifier.showChat.rawValue, sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

internal final class ChatVC: UIViewController {

}

internal final class UsersListVC: UIViewController {

    internal var completion: (() -> ())? = nil

    @IBAction func close(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true) {
            [weak self] in self?.completion?()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you create a new instance of `MainVC` in your dismiss closure.

```
dismiss(animated: true) { 
    MainVC().showChatVC()
}
```

Since this new ViewController is never shown on screen, it also cannot show another ViewController.

Try getting a reference to your existing `MainVC`.

```
dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
    if let mainVC = self?.presentingViewController as? MainVC {
        self?.mainVC.showChatVC()
    }
}
```

Otherwise try using the Notification approach.